# How to enable menu tool bar in web par?

Tags: 2010, web-part, sharepoint-enterprise

One of my web parts looks like the following

[image: Documents web part]

But my other web parts doesn't have a tool bar like the one above.  How can I enable that tool bar with New, Upload, Actions and Settings options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit your webpart and look for Toolbar Type and select from the drop down options. The one your looking for is "Show Toolbar"